# Give team lead a couple of subtle hints, how?

Tags: team, leadership, teamwork, team-building

Here's the situation:
I've been with the company for quite a long time working with same people. From time to time we're organized into teams to work on different projects and about a week I joined one of those (they had started a month ago). Team Lead is a nice guy, but honestly I don't quite like some of his ways. Things that bugger me the most:

- Too many 'I' and 'me', like 5-6 in one sentence.
- Related to the first
  one: with his messages he (unwittingly I'm sure) draws clear line
  between 'I, person who decides what and how to do' and 'you, guys who
  do as I say'

I honestly believe that an effective team lead shall be part of a team, which means it should rather be 'it would be good if we do it like that, lets discuss if you don't agree', rather than 'I'd like you to do it like that'. Etc.

Now the question: are there any good **short** articles/posts in the internet covering the topic ? I would share it with the team as 'an interesting reading', hoping the team lead does get the hint :)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of hints, especially for us in software development where many of us are not the most adept at catching social cues. That said, [Rands in Repose](http://randsinrepose.com/) is far and away the best online resource I've found about leadership - especially for software development. Though this is likely off-topic since it doesn't have a single clear answer.

Comment: Agreed, usually hints are not good. But the situation is that I'm more senior than him and I really don't want this to look like mentoring.

Comment: More senior in the sense that you are older or that you have more years of experience, or more senior in that the team lead reports to you?

Comment: @Vlad - why wouldn't you want it to look like mentoring?

Comment: I'm a bit older, I've got more experience and my position is 'senior software engineer' while he's 'software engineer' as of yet.

@Telastyn From my personal experience people, and **especially** software engineers, don't like to be mentored. Especially by someone reporting to them.

Comment: @Vlad - understandable. Thanks for that, as it helps clarify for people looking to give advice.

Comment: Frankly anything you do at this point will look like sour grapes that he was selected to be lead and you were not.

Comment: Just as a matter of language: Some people don't get "subtle hints", but those people usually don't mind being told something bluntly. Others appreciate subtle hints a lot and get very upset at you if you are blunt. Use "subtle hints" on the right people.

Answer (score 5):

So the team leader is in charge. Period. His management style is different from yours - that doesn't make it a bad management style. He uses a lot of "I's" and he is prescriptive - tells you exactly what to do. On the other hand, it's his head that's on the chopping block if the tasks aren't done and the deadlines and milestones are not met. To me, that gives him the right to say "I" as much as he likes.

He has the right to have a management style that's different from yours. Let me rephrase it: he has as much right to his management style as you do to yours, if you were in charge. At the end of the day, it's results that count and results will be what he will be evaluated on, whatever his management style.

So far as I see, the fact that his management style and yours are different is a non-issue.